# window.location.replace generating history when used in ASP.Net code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a button on clicking it emits Javascript that will redirect user to  google.com. As i dont want this redirection to generate an item in history i use window.location.replace but it generate history item.

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "window.location.replace('http://google.com');";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Redirect", url, true);
    }
```

Any one have any idea how to deal with it .

Comment: What's wrong if history is generated even ??

Comment: that's the reason of using location.replace instead of location.href

Answer (score 1):

If you are not in a callback then you can try :

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('http://google.com');</script>/</head></html>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try this :

```
var len = history.length;
history.go(-len);
window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a server-side event handler to get javascript? This is probably the cause of your problem.

The way ASP.Net works is that when you click one of the `<asp:button />` with an OnClick handler (the code you have posted) the browser posts back the entire `form` to the server to find out what to do. This is a new history event. Therefore you will have two history entries in your log. I'm guessing that the page will then return a new version of your page with the javascript and run, redirecting clientside, replacing only the new history event, not the old one. That is why you're getting something in the history.

The way to fix this is to simply not to use a server-side `OnClick` event, an ASP.Net button to do this. Simply use javascript. It's pointless to post back to the server to get javascript that could have been served in the initial request.

As a good rule of thumb, any time you find yourself doing anything javascript related in C# code it's almost always going to be the wrong way of doing it.